# angular-drag-and-drop-lists simple demo doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

I was having a problem getting the simple demo to work [found here.](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple)

I'm getting the two lists to show up, however I am unable to drag and drop items. The demo is very simple, just an html file, javascript file and css file.

Here's my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Drag & Drop Demo</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/angular-drag-and-drop-lists.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/my-app.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/my-styling.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body class="simpleDemo" ng-controller="SimpleDemoController">
    <ul dnd-list="list">
        <li ng-repeat="item in models.lists.A"
            dnd-draggable="item"
            dnd-moved="models.lists.A.splice($index, 1)"
            dnd-effect-allowed="move"
            dnd-selected="models.selected = item"
            ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}">
            {{item.label}}
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul dnd-list="list">
        <li ng-repeat="item in models.lists.B"
            dnd-draggable="item"
            dnd-moved="models.lists.B.splice($index, 1)"
            dnd-effect-allowed="move"
            dnd-selected="models.selected = item"
            ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}">
            {{item.label}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my js file:

```
angular.module("demo", []).controller("SimpleDemoController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.models = {
        selected: null,
        lists: { "A": [], "B": [] }
    };

    // Generate initial model
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        $scope.models.lists.A.push({ label: "Item A" + i });
        $scope.models.lists.B.push({ label: "Item B" + i });
    }

    // Model to JSON for demo purpose
    $scope.$watch('models', function (model) {
        $scope.modelAsJson = angular.toJson(model, true);
    }, true);

});
```

And here's my css file:

```
.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list],
.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] > li {
    position: relative;
}

.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] {
    min-height: 42px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] .dndDraggingSource {
    display: none;
}

.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] .dndPlaceholder {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    min-height: 42px;
}

.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] li {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] li.selected {
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    color: #3c763d;
}
```

This code is simply copied and pasted from the simple demo, just slightly modified to show lists A and B. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're forgetting ***Dependency Injection*** just replace

```
angular.module("demo", [])
```

with

```
angular.module("demo", ['dndLists'])
```

and it should work..

[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YDFPW98eQsnYXAhslPzI?p=preview)

## --Update--

I found some problem with your ***Markup*** as well you are referencing `list` in `<ul dnd-list="list>"` this will not work as you're referencing an `undefined` variable, you should be referencing the list you are using in the drag-able. for example for the first list you can change.

```
<ul dnd-list="list">
```

to

```
<ul dnd-list="models.lists.A">
```

and that should work properly now..

P.S I've updated the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YDFPW98eQsnYXAhslPzI?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it. I also had to change it to `models.lists.B` for the second unordered list as well.

Comment: @GabeMeister I left that part intentionally for you to figure our.. and you your welcome .. Glad I could help :)

Comment: @Minato - The plunkr has stopped working.  Any ideas why?  I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined" in angular.js, line 9037.  I get the same error when running with the latest versions of Angular 1.x.

Comment: @Minato - ignore my last comment.  The problem was that the plunkr linked in your PS didn't actually have the <ul dnd-list="models.lists.A"> corrections...

Comment: thanks a lot for this, this plunkr should be referenced on their website, or something similar. their on screen examples are not clear on everything

Comment: this is the corrected plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/4F1XmDchnoJvJoBEZ03h?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

you need the next: (that is the dependency injection)

```
app.requires.push('dndLists');
```

you are missing the ng-repeat in your angular it should look like this: (ng-repeat="(listName, list) in models.lists")

```
  <div ng-repeat="(listName, list) in models.lists" class="col-md-6 ng-scope">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title ng-binding">List A</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body ng-scope">
                <ul dnd-list="list" class="ng-scope">

                    <li ng-repeat="item in list"
                        dnd-draggable="item"
                        dnd-moved="list.splice($index, 1)"
                        dnd-effect-allowed="move"
                        dnd-selected="models.selected = item"
                        ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}"
                        dnd-disable-if="list.length < 2"
                        class="ng-binding ng-scope"
                        draggable="true">
                        {{item.label}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```